# How I do server path www?

Tags: server, apache2

I have server Ubuntu 14.04 and  installed LAMP.

I like to making root of `www.marinadev.com` now this `marinadev.com`. I do know where config of server.

```
sudo cp /etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf /etc/apache2/sites-available/marinadev.com.conf    
sudo nano /etc/apache2/sites-available/marinadev.com.conf
```

This is the content:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html
    ServerName  marinadev.com
    ServerAlias www.marinadev.com
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

And then:

```
sudo a2ensite marinadev.com.conf    
sudo service apache2 restart
```

Comment: You need to be more specific about your problem. What errors (if any) are you getting?